# Are there statistics of airports by flight cancellation rate?

Tags: air-travel, airports, statistics, innsbruck

Looking around on airports, some people claim that Innsbruck (INN) has a bad reputation because of fog. Some say they fly there a lot and there is no problem. All of this is anecdotal.

Is there any statistics on cancelled landings/flights by airport?

Comment: Can you give some insight as to why you're asking?  The thing is, the only day that matters is the day you fly so overall statistics are either 100% right or 100% wrong.  But you only find out at that moment.

Comment: We are going on a short skiiing trip so we really don't want to risk losing like a full day because the flight get rerouted to another airport. If we pick an airport with 95% right rather than 70% right that reduces our risk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many companies who keep track of statistics for flights and airports. Some of it is online and paying users often get more coverage in terms of historical data or more fine-grain details.

You can check [FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com) which have tons of statistics. [This page](http://www.flightstats.com/go/Media/stats.do) lists Airlines, Airport Arrival and Airport Departure delays.

Another slightly harder website to read is the [Bureau of Transport Statistics](https://www.bts.gov) where you can query statistics for different airlines, airports and time windows. Try [this page](http://www.transtats.bts.gov/ot_delay/OT_DelayCause1.asp?pn=1) for example. Pluging in ATL (Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport) for the last three months today shows that there are 4% carrier delays and 5.4% late arrivals there.

Comment: What does ATL stand for?

Comment: ATL is Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airport

Comment: Note that FlightStats only reports cancellations and delays for the last 30 days. From a statistical point of view, this seems almost worthless -- a single day of fog can skew the results completely. I wouldn't trust a statistic computed on less than a few years.

Comment: It depends what you want to predict. Averages over long period can be unusual too since some type of issues average out. On the other hand, the last 30 of weather, is much more relevant to the next 30 days than the average of the last 10 years (which would include all seasons).